# my slider takes up the whole screen what should I do

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, slider

I wanted to use the slider as banner pictures 800 x 400 but the slider is getting full screen when i want to test  this is the code I wrote Where will I write sizing?

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"  width="800" height="400">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/banner.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">


              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/banner2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/banner3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking since I don't have an example to look at, but from what it seems, just add a `width: 100px;` (or any other number). That should size it. I can give you a more descriptive answer if you show me an example.

Comment: is a screenshot or something ?

Comment: A screenshot would be fine.

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/P1rnn6.png  here

Comment: I see a 403 Forbidden. Not sure if thats supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to go use CSS to do this, I think Bootstrap has something to do with it not working in HTML.

```
.carousel .item {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
```